# undefined reference of library function

Tags: qt

i m trying to use DCMTK library built in MSVC in my qt application.although i have added libs in my .pro file like Libs+= -Ldcmtk/lib -ofstd -dcmdata..i have also include .h files of these libraries
but i m getting undefined reference error for each function i m calling of these library..
what i m missing..

Answer (score 3):

Function names are not the same in the libs - c++ standard does not define it so both msvc and g++ define them their own way.

Check this post. 
[Qt/mingw32 undefined reference errors... unable to link a .lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137323/qt-mingw32-undefined-reference-errors-unable-to-link-a-lib)

There are some work-arounds like this for instance (dll):
http://www.emmestech.com/moron_guides/moron1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an undefined reference error then you haven't linked to the correct library.

Comment: i have checked for lib i m adding becouse i also have source code of tha lib. even if i have created my own lib say testlib and included its header & lib in .pro file i getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You use Qt Creator?

Say you have a lib file named libodbc32.a Then you should add a lib like this:

LIBS += -L [path to the libodbc32.a] -L [path to libsystemc.a] -lodbc32 -lsystemc

So I think you have linked not in an appropriate way.