# Adding Bonjour (dns_sd.h) library to Qt in Windows

Tags: windows, qt, bonjour

I've been trying to properly add the open source dns_sd.h library provided by Apple. I am writing a program that uses the BonjourRegistrar class as demonstrated here:
[link text](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-bonjour.html)

I've already written my program on the Mac environment and now I am trying to port it to Windows. The Bonjour SDK comes with several classes, and I am quite confused onto how to correctly add the class to my Qt project. I have tried add the line:

```
win32:LIBS += c:\dnsssd.lib
```

in the .pro file with no success. Also, I attempted to add the dns_sd.h and dns_sd.c files into my project and got a couple of errors such as:

'UINT8': does not name a type
'INT8': does not name a type
'UINT16' does not name a type
'INT16' does not name a type

Finally, I am now trying to modify the lib file as described by xcimo in this link
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137323/qt-mingw32-undefined-reference-errors-unable-to-link-a-lib)

I do not know if I am using the correct command to properly modify these files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .lib distributed by Apple can be used only if you are compiling the Qt application with the MSVC compiler.

Otherwise, like you said, you need a GCC-compatible library (.a). To do that you need to do the following steps:

1. Run the **reimp** tool [0] on the .lib: `reimp dnssd.lib`. A file `DLLStub.obj` will be generated.
2. Run the **gendef** tool [1] on the .dll: `gendef dnssd.dll`. A file `dnssd.def` will be generated. The .dll can be obtained from: `C:\Windows\System32` if you are using the 32 bit or from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` for the 64 bit version.
3. Assemble the final .a: `dlltool -k -d dnssd.def -l libdnssd.a`.
4. Add the right path int the .pro file, to the newly created library: `LIBS += -L"/path/to/the/library/file" -ldnssd`

[0] - http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/mingw-utils/mingw-utils-0.4-1/

[1] - http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/gendef/gendef-1.0.1346/ - gendef is a better alternative to `pexports`, because it can convert the stdcall-type libraries from MSVC to the GCC ones, so you can get a proper .def file.

PS: I know the author got it working, but I felt there should be some more detailed instructions on how to get it done -- the information is scattered around the internet.

Comment: Hi, I have converted the dnssd.lib file to libdnssd.a, but QT is still complaining about the same error, 'UINT8' does not name a type.

Comment: @Jerry Well, that's certainly not a linking problem, but a compilation one :) That means that probably you are not including the proper header(s).

Comment: I just downloaded the Bonjour SDK.  reimp fails with dnssd.lib from the Bonjour SDK "reimp: dnssd.lib: invalid or corrupt import library"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
DEFINES += _WIN32
```

to your project file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you need to use reimp and dll tool to modify the lib library to a .a

Comment: Hi, would you mind give some details. I have no luck to solve the compile error.