# error: dns_sd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, bonjour

I'm trying to build a demo project using Bonjour, following [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-bonjour.html), but i'm getting this error:

> error: dns_sd.h: No such file or directory

It happens on this line:

```
#include <dns_sd.h>
```

Where do I get that header file?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341179/adding-bonjour-dns-sd-h-library-to-qt-in-windows ?

Comment: They don't mention where they got the header and libs from, though.

Comment: Does this help ? sudo aptitude install libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I just had this error on Ubuntu while trying to compile a project. This helped:

```
sudo apt-get install libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev
```

Comment: Thanks that also resolved the issue with installing dnssd ruby gem.

Comment: Did not help me: libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev is already the newest version

Answer (score 2):

You can find the mDNSResponder daemon code here:  http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/

You can download a tar file here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/mDNSResponder/

Comment: The latest version is mDNSResponder-379.38.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

You can use Avahi configured with mdnsresponder-compat