# error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member (while compiling Bonjour)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, bonjour

I've downloaded Bonjour following this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585202/492336

I'm trying to compile it for Windows, using VS2008, but I'm getting this error:

> error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member

The error is at `mDNSEmbeddedAPI.h`, at this place in the code:

```
#define NSEC_MCAST_WINDOW_SIZE 32
typedef struct
{
    //domainname *next;
    //char bitmap[32];
} rdataNSEC;
```

Since this is a well-known library released by Apple, I'm surprised that it would fail to compile, provided they ship it as a Visual Studio project.

Is it because I'm using VS2008? The project file originally shipped was for an older version - I think VS2005?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Beyond just the error above, I get all kinds of errors trying to compile mDNSResponder in Visual Studio. Was there a trick?

Comment: @TTar I did, in the end, yes, I even have the project buried somewhere. But if you're encountering problems, just ask them in a new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
typedef struct
{
    //domainname *next;
    //char bitmap[32];
} rdataNSEC;
```

you should use

```
 typedef struct rdataNSEC rdataNSEC;
 struct rdataNSEC{ };
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments just above the declaration of `rdataNSEC` (in `mDNSEmbeddedAPI.h`):

```
// ... The following is just a palceholder
// and never used anywhere.
```

So why not just comment out the declaration?