# QT dns_sd.h UINT8 does not name a type

Tags: windows, qt, bonjour, zeroconf

This is a zeroconf [example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-bonjour.html) I'm trying to compile on Windows. I also downloaded [bonjour sdk for Windows](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html)  from Apple.

I'm using Qt Version (4.6.2) and Qt Creator 1.3.1, not sure if it is relevant.

When I compile, it complains about 'UINT8' does not name a type in dns_sd.h. I tried to include stdint.h before dns_sd.h, shown as below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dns_sd.h>
```

But QT still complains about the same errors. Even though I go into stdint.h and there is a declaration for uint8_t.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341179/adding-bonjour-dns-sd-h-library-to-qt-in-windows) suggests to convert .lib to .a, since we can't link a gcc program to a MSVC lib. I tried but it did not solve the problem. Here is the .pro file

```
HEADERS       = client.h \
            bonjourservicebrowser.h \
            bonjourserviceresolver.h
SOURCES       = client.cpp \
            main.cpp \
            bonjourservicebrowser.cpp \
            bonjourserviceresolver.cpp
QT           += network

!mac:x11:LIBS+=-ldns_sd
win32:LIBS+=-ldnssd
LIBPATH += "C:/Tools/reimp_new/bin"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Bonjour SDK/Include"
```

I put the libdnssd.a in the path of C:\Tools\reimp_new\bin.

Error is still happening :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this before including dns_sd.h fixes it.

```
#define _MSL_STDINT_H
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dns_sd.h>
```

I also tried to use the original lib file, it still work. So probably there is no need to convert the .lib to .a